# SQLite query for finding best match in path column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column in my SQLite database that contains a file path.

Given an arbitrary file path, I need to return the **best match** for this file path

If the path column contains:

```
/my/folder/foo
/my/folder/foo/bar
/my/other_folder/other_foo
/my/other_folder/other_foo/other_bar
```

If I query with the path `/my/folder/foo/images/png/myimage.png` it should return `/my/folder/foo`

If I query with the path `/my/folder/foo/bar/pdf/mypdf.pdf` it should return `/my/folder/foo/bar`

note that the path used in the query is usually longer than the path stored at the table

I've been struggling with this using "normal" and "recursive" queries but no luck, so if anyone can provide any advice it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If I follow you correctly, we can filter on paths which match at the beginning of the the search param, then retain the path that has most characters.

So:

```
select *
from mytable
where :param like path || '/%'
order by length(path) desc
limit 1
```

... Where `:param` represents the input paramter of the query.

Comment: It is probably necessary to make this `like path || '/%'` in order not to return `'/my/folder/foo'` when asking for the folder for `'/my/folder/foolish/image.png'` :-)

Comment: simple and obvious solution!
I did not realized that the :param could be on the left side of the predicate :-(
Thank you all!